# How to print line number where object reference occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I need a suggestion regarding *Object reference* issue. I got this message *ExceptionMessage: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* (because some null object) I am printing the stack trace when an error occurs:

```
 Exception systemException = lastError.GetBaseException();
```

By using ex.Message I am able to get the method where exception has occurred but I am not getting any information regarding the line (of that method) where exception occurred. **I need to know at which line object reference has occurred and which object was null** when this exception came.

Comment: I'd imagine that the line number would be in the stack trace

Comment: I believe [this][1] is a similar question to the one you're asking


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817796/how-to-print-out-line-number-during-application-run-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line number is pretty much guaranteed to be in the stack trace.  If you want to drill down on it, put a try-catch in the large block of code where it might be happening and drop a breakpoint on the catch block, which will allow you to drop down through the InnerExceptions inside of visual studio (if any exist).

Answer (score 4):

You need the actual stacktrace:

```
systemException.StackTrace
```

If you want the line numbers, you will need to do something like this:

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(systemException, true);
StackFrame[] frames = st.GetFrames();

foreach(StackFrame frame in frames)
    frame.GetFileLineNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string a = null;
                a.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var s = ex.StackTrace;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Source);
                int st = s.LastIndexOf("line");
                Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(st, s.Length - st));
            }
        }
    }
```

Edited :

And yes I just learned, using StrackTrace in the answer posted by EkoostikMartin.
I think it is a better answer.